# Python Help (Printing conversion table)

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my second function to take all the temperature values from 225-350 F (multiples of 5) and print a table with the corresponding output using my first function.

here is the code:

```
 #candyTemperature ---> float, float ---> float

def candyTemperature(temperature, elevation):
candyTemperature = temperature - (elevation / 500)

return candyTemperature

 #candyTemperature(244,5280) = 233.44 degrees F

 #candyTemperature(300,29029) = 241.942 degrees F

 #temperatureTable ---> int ---> float

def temperatureTable(elevation):
    for temperature in range(225, 5, 350):
    candyTemperature(temperature, elevation)

    return candyTemperature
```

currently doesnt work, thanks for the help in advance.

EDIT: Ideally I would get a list with two columns, one displaying the original temperature, and the other with the adjusted temperature for elevation. One conversion for each value from 225-350 in 5s.

Comment: Please reformat your question so we can see the code.

Comment: What is not working? How would you like to see it work? What have you tried?

Comment: how does it not work? What are you getting? What do you expect to get? What have you tried?

Comment: I rolled back the edit, because it changed the indentation in a syntactically-significant way—in particular, it makes the `return` come outside of the `candyTemperature` function, breaking part of the code that used to (maybe) work. Also, there's a good chance the asker's problem actually is caused by indentation, so even fixing it correctly could ruin the question.

Comment: i'm new to programming and the site: any more information needed i'll provide quickly. thank you all!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def temperatureTable(elevation):
    tempTable = list()
    for temperature in range(225, 350, 5):
        candyTemp = candyTemperature(temperature, elevation)
        tempTable.append((candyTemp, temperature))
    return tempTable
```

Comment: tempperature is spelled incorrectly and would end up in error.

Comment: Also, the columns are not in the order requested by the OP.
Please reconsider your vote if my answer is helpful.

Comment: Also, there is no record corresponding to 350 in your output table. I would assume that was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Range function takes '(start, stop[, step])' params ([Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)).

In your case the loop statement should look like this:

```
# loop from 225 to 350 with step 5
for temperature in range(225, 350, 5):
```